# Single-Linked List in C - beginner

Tags: beginner, c, linked-list

I'm a python dev by day trying to learn C.

This is a simple implementation of a singly linked list. As a noob I would like comments on style and C conventions as well as functional remarks on memory management etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
        --------linkedList---------
        |                          |
        |                          |
        |                          |
        |                          | 
        *head  -->  nodes  -->   *end   
*/

struct linkedList {
    struct node * head;
    struct node * end;
    int len;
};
struct node {
    int id;
    int val;
    struct node * next;
};
struct linkedList * createList() {
    struct linkedList * l_list = (struct linkedList * ) malloc(sizeof(struct linkedList));

    l_list->head = NULL;
    l_list->end = NULL;
    l_list->len = 0;
    printf("created list\n");
    return l_list;
}

struct node * createNode(int id, int val) {
    struct node * n_node = (struct node * ) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    n_node->id = id;
    n_node->val = val;
    n_node->next = NULL;
    printf("created node\n");
    return n_node;
}

void addNode(struct linkedList * ptr, int id, int val) {
    struct node * new_node = createNode(id, val);
    if (ptr->len == 0) {
        ptr->head = new_node;
        ptr->end = new_node;
        ptr->len += 1;
        printf("created a list and added a new value\n");
    } else {
        // update next of previous end
        // make new end this node 
        struct node * temp;
        temp = ptr->end;
        temp->next = new_node;
        ptr->end = new_node;
        ptr->len += 1;
        // printf("updated a preexisting list\n");
    }
}

void printListWithFor(struct linkedList * someList) {
    struct node currentNode = * someList->head;
    printf("current length of list is %d\n", someList->len);
    printf("first item is %d, last item is %d\n", someList->head->val, someList->end->val);
    if (currentNode.next == NULL) {
        printf("current node id is %d, with a value of %d\n", currentNode.id, currentNode.val);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ( * someList).len; i++) {
        printf("current node id is %d, with a value of %d\n", currentNode.id, currentNode.val);
        currentNode = * currentNode.next;
    }
}

void printListWithWhile(struct linkedList * someList) {
    struct node currentNode = * someList->head;
    struct node endNode = * someList->end;
    printf("current length of list is %d\n", someList->len);
    printf("first item is %d, last item is %d\n", someList->head->val, someList->end->val);
    if (currentNode.next == NULL) {
        printf("current node id is %d, with a value of %d\n", currentNode.id, currentNode.val);
    }
    while (currentNode.id != endNode.id) {
        printf("current node id is %d, with a value of %d\n", currentNode.id, currentNode.val);
        currentNode = * currentNode.next;
    }
    printf("current node id is %d, with a value of %d\n", currentNode.id, currentNode.val);
}
struct node * findNode(struct linkedList * someList, int id) {
    struct node headNode = * someList->head;
    struct node endNode = * someList->end;
    struct node * nullNode = createNode(-1, -1);

    if (headNode.id == id) {
        free(nullNode);
        return someList->head;
    }
    if (endNode.id == id) {
        free(nullNode);
        return someList->end;
    }
    struct node * currentNode = headNode.next;
    while (currentNode-> id != endNode.id) {
        if (currentNode->id == id) {
            free(nullNode);
            return currentNode;
        }
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }
    return nullNode;
}

int delNode(struct linkedList * someList, int id) {
    struct node * headNode = someList->head;
    struct node * endNode = someList->end;

    if (headNode->id == id) {
        // remove node, replace it with next node, free memory
        struct node * temp = headNode->next;
        someList->head = temp;
        printf("removed a node with id of %d and value of %d\n", headNode->id, headNode->val);
        free(headNode);
        someList->len -= 1;
        return 0;
    }
    if (endNode->id == id) {
        printf("removed a node with id of %d and value of %d\n", endNode->id, endNode->val);
        free(endNode);
        someList->len -= 1;
        return 0;
    }
    struct node * currentNode = headNode->next;
    struct node * prevNode = headNode;
    while (prevNode->id != endNode->id) {
        if (currentNode->id == id) {
            struct node * temp = currentNode->next;
            prevNode->next = temp;
            printf("removed a node with id %d and value of %d\n", currentNode->id, currentNode->val);
            free(currentNode);
            someList->len -= 1;
            return 0;
        }
        prevNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }
    return -1;

}
int main() {

    struct linkedList * list = createList();
    addNode(list, 1, 7);
    addNode(list, 2, 6);
    addNode(list, 3, 11);
    addNode(list, 5, 92);
    addNode(list, 18, 6);
    addNode(list, 10, 3);
    addNode(list, 50, 9);

    // printListWithWhile(list);
    // printListWithFor(list);
    printf("\n");
    struct node * foundNode = findNode(list, 1);
    printf("Node id : %d\n", foundNode->id);
    printf("Node val : %d\n", foundNode->val);

    printf("\n");
    // printListWithWhile(list);
    delNode(list, 2);
    printListWithWhile(list);
    delNode(list, 18);
    printf("\n");
    printListWithWhile(list);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, it's not necessary or desirable to cast the return value from `malloc()`.  It is however *essential* to check the result isn't null before dereferencing it:

```
struct linkedList *createList() {
    struct linkedList *list = malloc(sizeof *list);
    if (list) {
        list->head = NULL;
        list->end = NULL;
        list->len = 0;
    }
    return list;
}
```

Note that the caller of `createList` *also* needs to check whether the returned list pointer is null before attempting to use it.

There doesn't seem to be a corresponding function to release a list; this is likely what makes the test program leak memory.  See this Valgrind output:

```
==868== HEAP SUMMARY:
==868==     in use at exit: 104 bytes in 6 blocks
==868==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 4 frees, 1,176 bytes allocated
==868== 
==868== 104 (24 direct, 80 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 6
==868==    at 0x483577F: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==868==    by 0x109186: createList (217145.c:24)
==868==    by 0x1096D7: main (217145.c:151)
```

We can't rely on the node `id` values being unique:

> ```
> if (currentNode.next == NULL) {
>     printf("current node id is %d, with a value of %d\n", currentNode.id, currentNode.val);
> }
> while (currentNode.id != endNode.id) {
>     printf("current node id is %d, with a value of %d\n", currentNode.id, currentNode.val);
>     currentNode = * currentNode.next;
> }
> ```

This looks very weird, because it is copying the entire value of each node into `currentNode`.  A more efficient and more idiomatic approach is to define `currentNode` as a pointer; since we don't want to modify the list through it, make it a pointer to `const`.

```
void printListWithWhile(const struct linkedList * someList)
{
    const struct node *currentNode = someList->head;
    printf("current length of list is %d\n", someList->len);
    if (someList->head) {
        printf("first item is %d, last item is %d\n",
               someList->head->val, someList->end->val);
    }

    while (currentNode) {
        printf("current node id is %d, with a value of %d\n",
               currentNode->id, currentNode->val);
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }
}
```

Or more idiomatically (though now belying the name) as a `for` loop:

```
void printListWithWhile(const struct linkedList * someList)
{
    printf("current length of list is %d\n", someList->len);
    if (someList->head) {
        printf("first item is %d, last item is %d\n",
               someList->head->val, someList->end->val);
    }

    for (const struct node *currentNode = someList->head;  currentNode;  currentNode = currentNode->next) {
        printf("current node id is %d, with a value of %d\n", currentNode->id, currentNode->val);
    }
}
```

These observations apply to most of the functions.

Other odd things:

- Why does `findNode()` create a dummy object to return on failure, rather than just returning `NULL`?
- And why waste resources creating it in the cases where it's simply deleted again?
- What does the return value of `delNode()` signify?  A common convention is true (i.e. non-zero) for success and false (zero) if not found; is there a reason for a different convention here?
- `printListWithFor()` never seems to be called.
- Lots of commented-out code and unnecessary `printf()`s seem to have been left in when debugging.  These should be removed before the code is ready to use.

Comment: You wouldn't recommend using typedef for the node and list type?

Comment: I don't have a strong opinion, though it can make code easier to read.  You're welcome to post an answer of your own, of course...

Comment: I think `typedef` is overused by beginners; I would not use it if you have a choice. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html#typedefs.

Comment: You may also want to mention that the argument to `printListWithWhile` should be `const` and that generally, one would just name that `printList`.

Comment: Thanks @Edward; I've updated the argument to that function.  The naming is unconventional, but OTOH, I can see that it's done for (auto?)didactic purposes, to compare two ways of terminating the loop, so I think that wasn't a mistake.

Comment: @Edward they are named that way on purpose for the exact reason Toby mentioned.

Comment: @TobySpeight The reason I returned a dummy object was because I didn't realise I could simply return Null. But in hindsight I realise I'm returning a pointer not a struct allowing for the Null return.

Comment: @TobySpeight also in regards to the return statement of `delNode`, I was copying bash where success is zero and I just assumed it was the same in C but now I know.